# MYSQL join on condition1 else join on condition2

Tags: php, mysql

I've got two tables where I want to `JOIN` one with the other. The `JOIN` works fine, but I get two records returned. This is (looking at my query) correct, but I need to return one of the two records based on a condition. Can this be managed with a single query?

table `oc_order_product`:

```
product_id | name  | quantity | order_id | store_url
51         | prod1 | 1        | 17       | http://www.opencarttest.com/
48         | prod2 | 3        | 17       | http://www.opencarttest.com/
```

table `product`:

```
oc_product_id | price | store_url
51            | 50.00 | http://www.opencarttest.com/
51            | 89.95 | 
48            | 15.00 |
```

My current query:

```
SELECT
  oop.product_id,
  oop.name,
  oop.quantity,
  p.price,
  p.store_url
FROM
  oc_order_product AS oop
JOIN
  product AS p
ON
  p.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
WHERE
  oop.order_id='17' AND oop.store_url='http://www.opencarttest.com/'
```

This returns:

```
product_id | name  | price | store_url
51         | prod1 | 50.00 | http://www.opencarttest.com/
51         | prod1 | 89.95 | 
48         | prod2 | 15.00 |
```

But I need only this:

```
product_id | name  | price | store_url
51         | prod1 | 50.00 | http://www.opencarttest.com/
48         | prod2 | 15.00 |
```

I only need one result from product that matched the oc_product_id. But it can be one of both products. I need the product with the store_url equals the `oc_order_product.store_url`, or else the product without the store_url.

**EDIT:** Added trailing slashes

Comment: @Tularis that will not work - it'll produce exactly the same result.  Also left join is totally wrong here

Comment: @Tularis, changed the query, but now I get a `null` result for the price of product_id `48`. From the two products with product_id I now only get the product with the store_url. So that looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you what you are looking for, however at the expense of performance:

```
SELECT
  oop.product_id,
  oop.name,
  oop.quantity,
  p.price,
  p.store_url
FROM
  oc_order_product AS oop
JOIN
  product AS p
ON
  p.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
  and
  (p.store_url = oop.store_url
   or
   not exists (select 1 from product where oc_product_id=p.oc_product_id and store_url is not null)
  )
WHERE
  oop.order_id='17' AND oop.store_url='http://www.opencarttest.com'
```

Here is the [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7e91/4/0).

Note that with your specific data as shown in the question, this won't work - and neither will your own query - as you have URL's with the trailing slash in one table and without it in the other.  In my example, I removed trailing slashes in all places.

Comment: I will go for your answer, since I can follow the MYSQL statement. I updated my question with the trailing slash, my mistake, they should be in all tables! Great, many thanks!

Answer (score 2):

**Updated** - I made an assumption that fields were empty strings instead of NULLs

Thanks to @aleks-g since I stole his [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a7e91/7) for this code test

Here is one way - Using LEFT JOINs and COALESCES

```
SELECT
  oop.product_id,
  oop.name,
  oop.quantity,
  COALESCE(p_filled.price, p.price) AS price,
  COALESCE(p_filled.store_url, p.store_url) AS store_url
FROM oc_order_product AS oop
LEFT JOIN product AS p_filled
ON p_filled.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
  AND oop.store_url= p_filled.store_url
LEFT JOIN product AS p
ON p.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
  AND COALESCE(p_filled.store_url,'') = ''
WHERE
  oop.order_id='17' AND oop.store_url='http://www.opencarttest.com';
```

Comment: Whow.. never heard of `COALESCES`. Never to old to learn ;). This gives the same results as Tularis mentioned with adding `AND (oop.store_url = p.store_url OR oop.store_url = '')` in the ON section. Getting `NULL` for the price.

Comment: Well, they where just empty values and that didn't work with you query. But because @aleks-g used `null`, I change my db and changed the field to `null` and now both you queries are working fine!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mysql variable in your query to record the occurrence of product id and by using `CASE` you can check either product has url OR product is not repeated then select it,some columns in query are just to elaborate the working

```
SELECT
  oop.product_id,
  oop.name,
  oop.quantity,
  p.price,
  p.store_url,
(CASE when @test=oop.product_id then 'repeated'
else 'new' end) occurance,
(CASE when p.store_url =oop.store_url OR @test!=oop.product_id
 then 'has'
else 'none' end) url,
@test:=oop.product_id `testvar`
FROM
  oc_order_product AS oop
join (SELECT @test:=0) t
JOIN
  (SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY store_url DESC) AS p
ON
  p.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
WHERE
  oop.order_id='17' 
HAVING url='has'
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e974a/22)

Comment: Thank for you support. Your query works like charm, but for me difficult to read. So I'm going for the query I'm able to understand. Also this query looks a little bit slower than the other answers!

Comment: I think you need to add an ORDER BY. Your solution appears to require the URL to come before the same product with without the URL. Please see this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bec7bb/3 - Notice how the row he wanted is not marked HAS (All I did was re-arrange the order of INSERTS and remove the HAVING clause to show the detail)

Comment: @AgRizzo yes you were right there is a need of an order by clause and also in your provided fiddle urls are not same one is missing the trailing slash

Answer (score 0):

```
$rs = $db->Select('products p, products_images pi','p.*,image_id',"p.product_id=pi.product_id","product_id=$a1");
```

Comment: It would help if you could give an explanation of your line of code. How does it solve the problem, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Here's another way to do it, without requiring a subquery:

```
SELECT
  oop.product_id,
  oop.name,
  oop.quantity,
  IFNULL(p1.price, p2.price),
  p1.store_url
FROM
  oc_order_product AS oop
LEFT JOIN
  product AS p1
ON
  p1.oc_product_id = oop.product_id AND p1.store_url = oop.store_url
LEFT JOIN
  product AS p2
ON
  p2.oc_product_id = oop.product_id
WHERE
  oop.order_id='17'
  AND oop.store_url='http://www.opencarttest.com/'
  AND p1.oc_product_id IS NOT NULL OR p2.oc_product_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: Your 2nd LEFT JOIN makes this basically the same as the original query